# For Loop - Compare Unsigned Number With Signed Integer

Tags: c, for-loop

I am trying to compare an unsigned number with a signed number in a `for` loop, but it is not executing the statement after the for loop, which means the `for` loop is not working, I think.  My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   unsigned int i;
   for (i = 8; i >= -1; i--)
     printf ("%d\n", i);
   return 0;
}
```

In the code above, the `printf` statement is not getting executed, so what is wrong with my `for` loop. Can't we compare an unsigned number with a signed number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
unsigned int i;
for (i = 8 ; i >= -1; i--)
```

`-1` is converted to the largest value in an unsigned type for the comparison. Thus, for `unsigned` values,

```
i >= -1
```

is only true for `i = UINT_MAX`.

To get the intended output, the simplest way is to use signed integers, e.g. `int`.

Another way is to do a bit of magic in the loop control:

```
for(i = 8+1; i-- > 0;)
```

But if you do that, be sure to write a comment explaining the unusual loop control code.

Comment: i-- > 0 is beyond ugly.

Comment: Should I have written it `i --> 0`? ;)

Answer (score -1):

It is usually a good idea to declare variables as unsigned if they will be compared to sizes, to avoid this issue.

Compilers give warnings about comparing signed and unsigned types because the ranges of signed and unsigned ints are different, and when they are compared to one another, the results can be surprising. If you have to make such a comparison, you should explicitly cast one of the values to be compatible with the other, perhaps after checking to ensure that the value you are casting is valid.